# No results when exporting database from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When I export a database from phpmyadmin, the only result I get is a file containing this text (instead of the structure of the database):

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.6deb4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Apr 09, 2019 at 12:23 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1
-- PHP Version: 7.0.33-0+deb9u3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: [DB_Name]
--

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

The database is on a server hosted on GCP and we recently migrated our domain to a new domain but I'm not sure why/how it can impact the export results. We were able to export with no issues prior to moving to a new domain. Any help on how to resolve this is much appreciated.
UPDATE: The exact same process works with another database. So it is related to this one only.

Comment: I get the feeling you did not tell phpMyAdmin which database to export

Comment: It says "Exporting tables from [DB_Name] database" at the top of the export page. Is there a way that the server cannot access it somehow when I initiate export?!

Comment: Click on the database in the left hand menu. Then use the EXPORT that you see in the tabs

Comment: That's exactly how I did it.

Comment: This is a phpmyadmin issue. I worked around the problem by exporting from the commandline using mysqldump.